# set role for specific users group that have access to just specific plugin page in wordpress admin panel

Tags: wordpress, content-management-system

i want to set role for specific users group that have access to just specific plugin page in wordpress admin panel when they login to my website and other part of admin panel gone hide for they.

Answer (score 0):

I am looking for the same plugin.

Here what I have found, these are all free:

[Members](http://wordpress.org/plugins/members/)

[User Specific Content](https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-specific-content/)

[User Access Manager](http://wordpress.org/plugins/user-access-manager/)

The following is a paid plugin:

[PrivateContent](http://www.projects.lcweb.it/privatecontent?lc_preview)